# Handling parameters of different length in COBOL

Tags: pointers, cobol

If a caller passes a parameter of different length (e.g different record type) to a callee how to properly handle that in COBOL. One way to work-around this situation is

calee defines different type of records in LINKAGE SECTION and get addressability using the parameter.

```
LINKAGE SECTION. 
01  recx       pic x(10).
01  recy       pic x(1000).
01  recz       pic x(25).

01  rectype    pic x(01).
01  rec        pic x(1).
PROCEDURE DIVISION USING rectype rec.


EVALUTE TRUE

when rectype='x'
SET ADDRESS OF recx to ADDRESS of rec
when rectype='y'
SET ADDRESS OF recy to ADDRESS of rec
when rectype='z'
SET ADDRESS OF recz to ADDRESS of rec
```

Would it be the right way to handle this situation.

Answer (score 4):

No, not really.

```
LINKAGE SECTION. 
01  recx       pic x(10).
01  recy
    REDEFINES recx       pic x(1000).
01  parm       pic x(1).
01  rectype    pic x(01).
    88  use-recx VALUE "X".
    88  use-recy VALUE "Y".
PROCEDURE DIVISION USING parm
                         rectype
                         recx.

EVALUTE TRUE
  when use-recx
    PERFORM process-recx
  when use-recy
    PERFORM process-recy
END-EVALUATE

GOBACK
.
```

The `USING ... recx` causes recx to get the address of the second parameter on the CALL. Due to the REDEFINES, recy also gets the same address. If you have a recz as well, that can also be made a REDEFINES of recx.

Then the second parameter can be used to identify which of the different data structures are available on that particular CALL.

If there is something in the same location on both structures which allows identification of the two structures, that can also be used instead of needing `rectype`.

The LINKAGE SECTION itself is just a bunch of definitions which can be used once an address has been assigned to them. If you have 300 programs CALLing your program with 291 different data-structures at 514 different addresses, it does not matter, because all the CALLed program sees is the address of the current data-structure for the current CALL.

The USING on the PROCEDURE DIVISION (or the ENTRY statements) causes code to be generated which loads the address of storage "passed" such that the 01-level (or 77, but don't do that) named on the USING has that address. So all your different structures can be REDEFINESed and they will all automatically, when you reference them, have the address which has been passed to the CALLed program.

If you look at your output listing, when you have done the REDEFINES, you'll notice that all of those structures use the same `BLL CELL`. They are all just mappings available for the address of the data for the current CALL.

You *could* do it your way, but it would be a duplication of effort. The compiler would do the equivalent of a SET for the first item on the USING, then you would do an actual SET for that same address to manually assign it to one of your structures. As well as duplication, it introduces another point at which an error could be introduced.

A further way to do it, which is becoming more common, is to pass a block of pointers, and then use SET for the data pointed to. This is seen as a more flexible way of being able to add new parameters to a program without having to change an recompile everything. However, again there is an extra burden on getting it right. More flexibility, less obvious, more difficult (relative) to get correct.

At the end of all that, the way to do it is the way that it is done at your site. No-one wants to pick up a program and have to understand the way something technically works before they even get a chance to look at the business logic. If you do it differently, your different code will always be viewed with suspicion - "there's an error here, and here's this strange code, I'm going to put some DISPLAYs in and see what is going on" rather than looking for the actual problem.

Comment: I have edited to correct the SET syntax and to include the missing variable. Caller has independent record structures, so redefinition is not needed. consider say 30 different record structures and none of them share same storage.

Comment: The REDEFINES is nothing to do with whether they share storage, it is to do with whether they share the parameter-list that is passed, whether they all take the address of the second item in the parameter list. I'll update the answer shortly.